# What does "go" refer to?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

At the ice rink in *Molly's Game* (2017), Molly fights with her psychiatrist father Larry after meeting
him long time:

> Father: It's funny how much faster you can **go** when you're not charging
> by the hour.

What does "go" refer to?
I understand by saying "It's funny how much faster you can go when you're not charging
by the hour," he is suggesting that therapy sessions can be more productive or
efficient when they are not limited by the time constraints imposed by billing by the hour.

Comment: My guess is that "Charging by the hour" does not create a time constraint or a burden – it's an incentive to spin out the treatment over more sessions than might be needed, because it helps to keep the appointment book full.

Comment: It's not *actually* a psychiatric consultancy session - which the father is somewhat cynically making a comparison with. But within a couple of minutes he's diagnosed all her problems as being down to a "trivial, *meaningless*" accident (tripping over a stick) which dashed her hopes of being an Olympic champion skier. It's a *joke*, but I don't think Molly herself sees anything funny about it (but we the movie audience see ***black** humour*).

Comment: [after not seeing him for a long time] She is ice skating. She can go faster than him because she does not have to receive payment from anyone to skate. It's a joke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The father's statement implies without the burden of charging by the hour, treatment sessions can be more successful and go at a faster speed.